# Laravel 5 Breadcrumb group issue

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have issue with grouping breadcrumbs. Following is my code:

```
Breadcrumbs::register('front', function($breadcrumbs) {
    $breadcrumbs->push('Home', URL::to('/'));
});

Breadcrumbs::group(['prefix' => 'front', 'parent' => 'front'], function($breadcrumbs)
{
    Breadcrumbs::register('product', function($breadcrumbs) {
        $breadcrumbs->push(trans('front.product'), route('product'));
    });

});
```

And following **error occurs:**

> FatalErrorException in
>   /project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php
>   line 219: Call to undefined method
>   DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\Manager::group()

I am trying to use breadcrumb as per following example, but no luck:
https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs/issues/84

Answer (score 0):

Fast Breadcrumbs, don't forget create layout for optimize code.
**@include('page.breadcrumbs')**

```
<nav class="breadcrumb" style="font-size: 18px;">

    <?php $breadcrumb = ''?>

    @for($i = 0; $i <= count(Request::segments()); $i++)

        <?php $breadcrumb .= Request::segment($i).'/'; ?>

        @if($i == 1)
            <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="{{url($breadcrumb).'/inicio'}}">{{Request::segment($i).' / '}}</a>
        @elseif($i == count(Request::segments()))
            <a class="breadcrumb-item active" href="{{url($breadcrumb)}}">{{Request::segment($i)}}</a>
        @else
            <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="{{url($breadcrumb)}}">{{Request::segment($i).' / '}}</a>
        @endif


    @endfor
</nav>
```